# How to get a popup window in a Firefox Webextension

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I've ported a chrome webextension to firefox using the following tutorial, https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/10/porting-chrome-extensions-to-firefox-with-webextensions/.

I managed to get the addon installed in Firefox but unlike my chrome counterpart, I am unable to open a popup window.

In chrome, my JS file called through my manifest has the following line of code

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  createPopup(tab.url)
})

function createPopup(url) {
    new_window = window.open('https://www.myurl.com?external=true&share_url='+url,'My site','height=600px,width=600px');
}
```

This works fine and pops up the window I need, but when I run it in firefox, I get the following error:

[Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: moz-extension://282abc47-9416-3a4e-a2f6-f090514fbabc/popup.js :: createPopup :: line 7"  data: no]

Comment: What version of Firefox did you run this in?

Comment: To test my addon, I ran it on the nightly build

Comment: This is a very un-extension-y way to open a popup. What happened to good old `chrome.windows.create`? That said, you're running into a bug in an unstable version of Firefox. I'm not sure what your question is - how to work around it?

Answer (score 3):

You might have run into this bug: [`window.open()` failing when invoked from a background page](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1282021). The bug suggests using extension-specific APIs to open a window as a workaround.

Comment: It would help if you included a one-liner example with `chrome.windows.open`.

Comment: Thank-you for volunteering!

Answer (score 0):

As I apparently *volunteered*, here's an example of extension-specific code that doesn't run into this:

```
function createPopup(url) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: 'https://www.myurl.com?external=true&share_url='+url,'My site',
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        type: 'popup'
    });
}

function createTab(url) { // Just in case you want a tab, not a separate window
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: 'https://www.myurl.com?external=true&share_url='+url
    });
}
```

Note that you won't get a reference to the newly opened document's `window`; you need a content script to interact with it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/openPopup